# How many times a specific character is in a String

Tags: java

How would I write a code fragment that determines and prints the number of times the character 'a' appears in a String object called name?

Comment: How would YOU write it? Lets start from there.

Comment: Step 1) Open text editor. Step 2) Try something.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to learn about the `charAt` method. Per the documentation, `charAt`

> Returns the char value at the specified index. An index ranges from 0 to length() - 1. The first char value of the sequence is at index 0, the next at index 1, and so on, as for array indexing.

```
for (int n = 0; n < myString.length(); n++){
    if (myString.charAt(n) == targetChar){
        sum++;
    }
}
return sum;
```

`myString` `sum` and `targetChar` aren't declared; you'll want to make them parameters (excluding `sum`) to a method.

### OR

As with every sitatuion, there are multiple ways to solve the problem. If you haven't learned about them yet, [enhanced for loops](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) seem like a perfect candidate for this problem.

```
for (char c : myString.toCharArray()){
    if (c == targetChar){
        sum++;
    }
}
return sum;
```

Comment: what's wrong with `for(char c : myString.toCharArray()){ ... }`??

Comment: nothing @BoristheSpider I've just gotten used to not using enhanced for-loops

Comment: _not_ using? For why?

Answer (score 0):

"Mandatory" Java 8 solution :

```
long count = myString.chars().filter(c -> c == 'a').count();
```